# event.target.style.cursor doesn't work IE

Tags: internet-explorer, raphael

I have this line of code:

```
event.target.style.cursor = "pointer";
```

It works fine in FF and Chrome, but not in IE7. I've looked all around for syntax for what would work with IE, but I'm coming up empty.

I should mention that my event.target is an svg shape that has gone through Raphaeljs.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In older IEs `event.target` is `event.srcElement`. In IE9 you can use also `target`. In this case you'll need to assign event handlers with `addEventListener()` method rather than using for example `onclick=some_function;`

See the example of using `event.srcElement` in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)